# Unicode problem with text in images in Python

Tags: python, image, firefox, unicode

I need to create in python an image with unicode chars like △ ▽ ◆ ◇ ◎ ◯ but I don't find the way.. I wonder how firefox or other programs print them well with the same font I use even.. this is my code

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

chars = u'△ 0x25b3, ▽ 0x25bd, ◅ 0x25c5, ◆ 0x25c6, ◇ 0x25c7, ◎ 0x25ce, ◯ 0x25ef'

img  = Image.new('L', (500,50), 255)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.text((0,0), chars, font=ImageFont.truetype('cour.ttf', 11))
img.save(r'D:\\test.jpg')
```

Comment: Browsers go to great lengths to find a font that contains each of the character(s) used on a web page. A page may be displayed using more than just one font. On the other hand, in a Python program you will need to select an appropriate font yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pick a font which contains those glyph's. Most likely the font face you are using, cour.ttf, does not contain the glyphs you are trying to write. You could try cyberbit.ttf.

Comment: Actually he doesn't necessarily need one font that covers everything (which is pretty much impossible, although MS has some fonts that cover quite a lot). No idea about python, but the basic idea would be what at least MS seems to call [font linking](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/07/16/185261.aspx)

Comment: I've found two fonts for now, a normal and a monospaced one.. but I'll definily need to find a way to use fonts in the user system, thanks for the link Voo